# Install MySQL on FreeBSD 8.2 without ports

Tags: mysql, freebsd, installation

I have downloaded and extracted the latest MySQL package from their website on my FreeBSD machine, I would like to install it. But I don't want to use the inbuilt ports, I want the latest version to be installed.

All tutorials I have looked at just show how to install from the ports.

Can anyone guide me on what I need to do to make a fully running MySQL database server on my machine.

Comment: Why don't you want to use ports?

Comment: The ports come with an older version of MySQL, i thought if I compile the latest build, at least I can update it when I need to. Also I tried the ports and it gave me an error upon compiling.

Comment: The ports use a *tested* version that contains patches that may or may not have been applied already upstream. If the port does not build, you have other problems that require attention.

Comment: The error was that it was needed swap space, I installed the system without a swap file. Just created one and everything was fine.

Comment: When problems arise with user-compiled versions of MySQL, the official answer from MySQL tends to be: "Use the vendor-compiled version." In FreeBSD, this translates to ports. The port version is compiled and tested by many folks with a lot of knowledge; I don't think I'd want to run a self-compiled version in a production environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow the directions for installing from the [source installation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/source-installation.html).

Comment: Wow I can't believe I forgot about the documentation. Thanks!